# Convert or render Word document to raster image

Tags: ms-word, png, doc, file-conversion

I got a bunch of Word templates (DOT files) and I need to provide a quick overview of their contents which has to be updated regulary. My only platforms available are Win32 and Win64.

Is there any way to batch convert several (many hundreds of) Word documents to a raster image format? Like a small command line utility which I can use in a small script?

I’d like to use PNG images and as I’m going to use `optipng` to optimize the images anyway the image format of the conversion doesn’t matter (as long as it’s not too exotic).

Answer (score 0):

Its hardly "small", but docx4j.NET can output to the various [formats supported by FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/output.html#bitmap).

Before you go to the effort of installing it, you can [test whether the results are good enough](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/demo_landing.html) for your purposes online.